# Replace None in list with average of last 3 non-None entries when the average is above the same entry in another list

Tags: python, list, loops, average

I have two lists:

```py
dataa = [11, 18, 84, 51, 82, 1, 19, 45, 83, 22]
datab = [1, None, 40, 45, None, None, 23, 24, None, None]
```

I need to replace all None in datab for any instance where the prior 3 entries are > than the data entry (see walk-through example below).
Ignore entries where there are not 3 prior non-None entries to average to make the comparison to dataa.

My first attempt was this:

```py
for i in range(len(dataa)):
        if (datab[i] == None):
                a = (datab[i-3]+datab[i-2]+datab[i-1])/3
                if ((datab[i-3]+datab[i-2]+datab[i-1])/3 > dataa[i]):
                        datab[i] = dataa[i]
```

It errors trying to compute the average of the prior three in the case where one of the prior 3 are None. I tried to keep a running total, but this fails for some of them.

```py
c = 0;
a = 0;
for i in range(len(dataa)):
        c = c + 1
        if (datab[i] == None):
                if (a > dataa[i]):
                        datab[i] = a
        else:
                if (c > 2):
                        a = (a * 3 + datab[i])/3
```

This also did not work as expected.

From this sample data, I expected:

- Entry 1, 2, and 3 have no average, so leave as is.
- Entry 5 is None in datab and 82 in dataa. Since `(1+40+45)/3 = 28.66` we also leave as is.
- Entry 6 is None in datab and 1 in dataa. The 3 prior non-None average are greater (`28.66 > 1`), so set to the 28.66 average.
- Entry 9 is None, but `(28.66+23+24)/3 = 25.22` is not greater than 83, so leave as is.
- Entry 10 is None and the 3 prior non-None average are greater (`25.22>22`), so set it to the 25.22 average.

The correct expected output:

```
[1, None, 40, 45, None, 28.66, 23, 24, None, 25.22]
```

Comment: Please explain `a = (a * 3 + datab[i])/3`.

Comment: Didn't work, but it was me trying to compute the running average of the non-None. Updated to clarify it didn't work ( and remove duplicate copy of data)

Comment: Don't you just want the average of the last 3 non-None elements?  Keeping a list of them instead of their average would make things much clearer and easier to do correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use a [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to keep track of our window of numbers to average, since popping off the top of a `deque` is cheaper than popping off the top of a list.

Thanks to [@ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger) for [pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75007435/replace-none-in-list-with-average-of-last-3-non-none-entries-when-the-average-is/75007701?noredirect=1#comment132366210_75007701) the `maxlen` feature of `deque`, which allows us to append an element, and the deque automatically pops the left element if needed.

```
from collections import deque

dataa = [11, 18, 84, 51, 82, 1, 19, 45, 83, 22]
datab = [1, None, 40, 45, None, None, 23, 24, None, None]

result = []

moving_avg = 0
sliding_window = deque(maxlen=3)

# Iterate over the two lists simultaneously
for a, b in zip(dataa, datab):
    # If b already has a value
    # Or the window has less than three items
    # Or the average is less than the element of dataa
    if b is not None or len(sliding_window) < 3 or moving_avg < a:
        # Append the element of datab to result
        result.append(b)
    else:
        # Else, append the moving average
        result.append(moving_avg)

    # If the value we just appended to our result is not None
    # Then append it to the sliding window
    if result[-1] is not None:
        sliding_window.append(result[-1])
    
    # Recalculate moving average
    moving_avg = sum(sliding_window) / len(sliding_window)
        
        
print(result) 
# [1, None, 40, 45, None, 28.666666666666668, 23, 24, None, 25.222222222222225]
```

You could save on some computation time by keeping track of the element being popped off the deque and using that to calculate the moving average, but for a deque of size 3 that shouldn't be such a big deal anyway.

Comment: Worked perfectly on test data and live data.

Comment: An improvement to use the features of `deque` better: 1) Change `sliding_window = deque()` to `sliding_window = deque(maxlen=3)`, and 2) Completely remove the `if len(sliding_window) >= 3: sliding_window.popleft()`. By setting the `maxlen` up front, you let `deque` handle popping off the oldest value for you (if the length is already equal to `maxlen`, e.g. `3` in this case, `sliding_window.append(result[-1])` implicitly pops off the leftmost value) more efficiently than you can code it.